# File seeking issue in Python

Tags: python

I try to write a J48 parseTree algorithm using Python
However, I encounter a weird problem:

```
def parseTree(f1):
   line = f1.readline()
   while not line.startswith("attribute"):
      f2.write(line);
      save = f1.tell();
      line = f1.readline()

print f1.tell()
print f1.readline()
f1.seek(1518)
print f1.readline()
```

the result is:

```
1518
attribute22 > 0    
te14 = Y
```

I am confused about why the two f1.readline() is not the same

this is part of the J48 tree:

```
=== Run information ===

Scheme:weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -C 0.25 -M 2
Relation:     cls-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R1,25-27,48-56
Instances:    60818
Attributes:   43
              cert_category
              attribute1
              attribute2
              attribute3
              attribute4
              attribute5
              attribute6
              attribute7
              attribute8
              attribute9
              attribute10
              attribute11
              attribute12
              attribute13
              attribute14
              attribute15
              attribute16
              attribute17
              attribute18
              attribute19
              attribute20
              attribute21
              attribute22
              attribute26
              attribute27
              attribute28
              attribute29
              attribute23_days
              attribute24_days
              attribute25_days
              attribute30
              attribute31
              attribute32
              attribute33
              attribute34
              attribute35
              attribute36
              attribute37
              attribute38
              attribute39
              attribute40
              attribute41
              attribute42_num
Test mode:10-fold cross-validation

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===

J48 pruned tree
------------------

attribute22 <= 0: 4 (406.0)
attribute22 > 0
|   attribute23_days <= 1
|   |   attribute14 = Y
|   |   |   attribute37 = Y: 0 (60.0/2.0)
|   |   |   attribute37 = N: 5 (17.0/1.0)
|   |   |   attribute37 = A: 0 (0.0)
|   |   attribute14 = N
|   |   |   attribute23_days <= 0: 5 (45.0)
|   |   |   attribute23_days > 0
|   |   |   |   attribute2 <= 26: 5 (20.0)
|   |   |   |   attribute2 > 26
|   |   |   |   |   attribute3 = Y: 5 (13.0)
|   |   |   |   |   at
```

Comment: Can you show how you open the file ? (text, binary, r, a ,a+) ?

Comment: can you try opening it in binary mode: open('j48.txt','rb') ? sometimes there are issues with seek function due to end line marks if file is not opened in binary mode